# Remove floor inside the model

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using ThreeJS to render house model. I try to make grass around the house. The problem is that if grass is an ordinary plane it appears inside the house (see first screenshot) and doesn't let go to a vault. I've tried to remove part of the floor using bounding box of the house, but it causes problems in other models (holes in the floor, see screenshot). I need some way to retain grass outside and remove inside the house, but I don't know how to do it.

[image: Inside the house]

[image: Outside the house]

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the current single grass plane with four bounded planes that do not enter the house.

```
+-----------+
|     1     |
+---+---+---+
| 2 |   | 3 |
+---+---+---+
|     4     |
+-----------+
```

**EDIT** another option is to use constructive solid geometry (CSG):

- http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/12/10/constructive-solid-geometry-with-csg-js/

Comment: This is just what I've done on the second screenshot. Four parts are not enough, as you can see.

Comment: I visited this link. The house is Object3D with holes inside, so if I try to subtract it from the grass I'll have the grass inside.

Comment: Perhaps you need to flatten your house along the vertical acids, then extrude it, then use CSG.

Comment: Can you advice how to flatten the house along vertical axis? I am new to three.js

Comment: Hmm. Actually this will only work if there are no parts of the building that overhang or underhang where the grass intersects the walls. But if that's the case, trace the contour of the 2D projection (truncate each position vector of one axis).

Comment: Can't you just adjust the sizes of rectangles 2 and 3 from my diagram?